# How to set HTTP status code for custom Thingworx service

Tags: http-status-codes, thingworx

Not able to set HTTP Status code for a custom ThingWorx service.

I need to send appropriate HTTP status code for error conditions in my Thingworx service. When I use GenericHTTPException, it sets the right code, but it prepends "Unable to Invoke Service" to my JSON response and that does not work for the AJAX client. I should be able to send pure JSON response along with the right HTTP status code

```
@ThingworxServiceDefinition(name = "GetServiceProviderHeirarchy", category = "PTC")
     @ThingworxServiceResult(name = "result", baseType = "JSON")
     public JSON GetServiceProviderHeirarchy(
                    @ThingworxServiceParameter(name = "seedURI", baseType = "STRING")String seedURI,
                    @ThingworxServiceParameter(name = "depth", baseType = "INTEGER")Integer depth,
                    @ThingworxServiceParameter(name = "resourceType", baseType = "STRING")String resourceType,
                    @ThingworxServiceParameter(name = "serverName", baseType = "STRING")String serverName)
                                throws Exception { 

     if(serverName == null || serverName.isEmpty()){
         JSONObject jsonErrObject = new JSONObject();
         jsonErrObject.put("message", "Values to input parameter serverName  is missing");
         logger.error("serverName is not provided");
         throw new InvalidRequestException(jsonErrObject.toString(), RESTAPIConstants.StatusCode.STATUS_BAD_REQUEST);
     }
}
```

Actual result:

> Unable to Invoke Service GetServiceProviderHeirarchy on
>   UpstreamOslcDataServicesThing : {"message":"No Configuration found for
>   resource type RequirementResourc. Please contact your administrator."}

Expected result:

> {"message":"No Configuration found for resource type
>   RequirementResourc. Please contact your administrator."}

Answer (score 0):

One possible option would be to include the jax-rs libraries as a ThingWorx resource and throw those specific exceptions as required. Say for bad request you can throw `javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException`'.

```
if(serverName == null || serverName.isEmpty()){
    String message = "No Configuration found for resource. Please contact your administrator.";
    throw new BadRequestException(message);
}
```